# What is the differences about struct in C99 to ANSI-C?

Tags: c, struct, c99, splint

This code doesn't appear to be correct in ANSI-C, but ok in C99 :

```
struct a { int x; int y; } z;
```

What are the differences about struct in C99 and ANSI-C ?

Edit: I forgot the "a", my bad. This code compiles ok with gcc in C99 mode, but is a parse error on splint, which is known to not support all the C99 extensions.

Edit2: here is the output of splint :

```
Splint 3.1.2 --- 19 Dec 2007

build/ecos_install/include/cyg/fileio/fileio.h:151:5:
Parse Error. Attempting to continue.
build/ecos_install/include/cyg/fileio/fileio.h:151:25:
Cannot recover from parse error.
*** Cannot continue.
```

Edit3: This file is the eCos fileio.h (the last line of this fragment is line 152) :

```
typedef CYG_ADDRWORD cyg_dir;

//=============================================================================
// Filesystem table entry

typedef int     cyg_fsop_mount    ( cyg_fstab_entry *fste, cyg_mtab_entry *mte );
typedef int     cyg_fsop_umount   ( cyg_mtab_entry *mte );
typedef int     cyg_fsop_open     ( cyg_mtab_entry *mte, cyg_dir dir, const char *name,
                                    int mode,  cyg_file *fte );
typedef int     cyg_fsop_unlink   ( cyg_mtab_entry *mte, cyg_dir dir, const char *name );
typedef int     cyg_fsop_mkdir    ( cyg_mtab_entry *mte, cyg_dir dir, const char *name );
typedef int     cyg_fsop_rmdir    ( cyg_mtab_entry *mte, cyg_dir dir, const char *name );
typedef int     cyg_fsop_rename   ( cyg_mtab_entry *mte, cyg_dir dir1, const char *name1,
                                    cyg_dir dir2, const char *name2 );
typedef int     cyg_fsop_link     ( cyg_mtab_entry *mte, cyg_dir dir1, const char *name1,
                                    cyg_dir dir2, const char *name2, int type );
typedef int     cyg_fsop_opendir  ( cyg_mtab_entry *mte, cyg_dir dir, const char *name,
                                    cyg_file *fte );
typedef int     cyg_fsop_chdir    ( cyg_mtab_entry *mte, cyg_dir dir, const char *name,
                                    cyg_dir *dir_out );
typedef int     cyg_fsop_stat     ( cyg_mtab_entry *mte, cyg_dir dir, const char *name,
                                    struct stat *buf);
typedef int     cyg_fsop_getinfo  ( cyg_mtab_entry *mte, cyg_dir dir, const char *name,
                                    int key, void *buf, int len );
typedef int     cyg_fsop_setinfo  ( cyg_mtab_entry *mte, cyg_dir dir, const char *name,
                                    int key, void *buf, int len );


struct cyg_fstab_entry
{
    const char          *name;          // filesystem name
    CYG_ADDRWORD        data;           // private data value
    cyg_uint32          syncmode;       // synchronization mode

    cyg_fsop_mount      *mount;
    cyg_fsop_umount     *umount;
    cyg_fsop_open       *open;
    cyg_fsop_unlink     *unlink;
    cyg_fsop_mkdir      *mkdir;
    cyg_fsop_rmdir      *rmdir;
    cyg_fsop_rename     *rename;
    cyg_fsop_link       *link;
    cyg_fsop_opendir    *opendir;
    cyg_fsop_chdir      *chdir;
    cyg_fsop_stat       *stat;
    cyg_fsop_getinfo    *getinfo;
    cyg_fsop_setinfo    *setinfo;
} CYG_HAL_TABLE_TYPE;
```

Comment: You sure? GCC with `-ansi -pedantic` will compile this just fine...

Comment: ANSI C is the (American copy of ISO) standard C language, with multiple versions: 89,95,99, after the years of standardization. Hence there is such a thing as ASNI C99, but ANSI C is ambiguous (refers to all versions)

Comment: the colloquial meaning of 'ANSI C' is ANSI X3.159-1989 aka C89 - I have never heard anyone using the term 'ANSI C' to refer to anything else...

Comment: @Christoph: Maybe for you, but for a general question, they're all ANSI C. If you mean a specific version then....

Comment: @MSalters: actually, there's no such thing as ANSI C99 - ISO C99 was adopted by ANSI in 2000

Comment: @Billy: the term 'ANSI-C' was coined when there was just the one C standard (ie ANSI C89, adopted by ISO in 1990), and this is for example still reflected in gcc's command line arguments; I myself use the less ambigious terms C90 and C99, but really, the first time I ever heard someone use the term ANSI C to refer to something different than C89 was here on SO

Answer (score 4):

```
struct { int x; int y; } z;
```

This code is valid C, with the same semantics, from every version of C since 1978 onwards, and probably a lot earlier. It defines a variable, called z, which has as its type a name-less struct type, which consists of two ints.

ofaurax, what error message do you get to conclude it doesn't work?

(Pedantic nit: "ANSI C" means the version of C standardized by ANSI, the American National Standards Institute. The 1989 version of the ANSI C standard was adopted by ISO, the International Standards Organization. In 1999 ISO made a new version of the C standard, which ANSI then adopted back.)

Edit:

```
struct a { int x; int y; } z;
```

This defines a struct type, called "struct a", consisting of two ints, and a variable, z, of that type. This is still well-formed even in the 1978 version of C ("K&R"). I don't know what split is, but the exact error messages would still probably help us figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the actual compiler warnings, compiler flags and the associated lines of your code? There is absolutely nothing wrong with your example. Or, perhaps a link to the document which led you to your conclusions?

If your trusting a compiler to tell you the difference, what compiler / version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

A file with just that code in it is parsed fine by [Splint 3.1.2](http://www.splint.org/).

Can you provide a simple, complete example which exhibits the behaviour you're describing?

A quick bit of experimenting says splint doesn't appear to support mixed code and declarations, which would put me off using it. So the code you posted *by itself* is ok, but this will give a parse error:

```
void foo () {
   int x = 1;
   ++x;
   struct a { int x; int y; } z;
}
```

This change to the grammar will allow it to parse the simple mixed code and declaration above, and it then *appears* to work but I've not tested it exhaustively.

```
$ diff original/src/cgrammar.y src/cgrammar.y
1711a1712
>  | initializer
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure, but in "old" compilers I remember having to write that as

```
typedef struct _Z {int x; int y;} z; or just typedef struct {int x; int y;} z;
```